# Waiting for result using synchronized block causes App freeze

Tags: java, android, task

I have an object `Task` (see `com.google.android.gms.tasks`)

I need to wait till It has finished all operations before return result.
So I have tried to create a dummy object

```
final static Object lock=new Object();
```

to use as lock and I have added in the method

```
synchronized(lock){
    lock.wait();
}
```

so that It doesn't return the value before task completion

calling `lock.notifyAll` in `onSuccess()` listener of the task (this listener is called when the task ends correctly).

But unfortunately the whole App freeze.

Why happens this?

How should I deal with Task completion?

(Note that Task isn't like `AsyncTask`)

Comment: In which Thread is `onSuccess()` called? If it is called in the same thread, you are blocking the execution of `onSuccess`, therefore never calling `lock.notifyAll()`, which will result in a deadlock - and your app freezes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to run a Task synchronously.

```
Tasks.await(yourTask);
```

But make sure this is called in a background thread.